# Does Java 8's ZonedDateTime take into account daylight savings when converting?

Tags: java-8, zoneddatetime

I have the following code below:

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(
            this.start.toLocalDateTime(), ZoneOffset.UTC,
            ZoneOffset.systemDefault());
```

The this.start is from a java.sql.Timestamp. I am explicitly converting from UTC here to the system's local offset, will this be smarty enough to take into account daylight savings?

Comment: Check the documentation here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ZonedDateTime takes daylight savings into account. That's what differs it from LocalDateTime. Well, that and timezone information.